# Recursive call in swift

Tags: swift

I am confused with the following recursive example. The place where recursion happens, the local variable needs to be updated every time. I wonder then how it could store the base result? And `let` variable is not mutable, how it updates?

The question is as follows for the following solution:

> Implement a recursive function named digits that takes a positive
>   integer number and return an array containing it’s digits in order.
>
> Function call:
>
> digits(123)
>
> Function output:
>
> [1, 2, 3]

```
func digits(_ number:Int) -> [Int]
{
    if number >= 10 {
        // confusion in the following line
        let firstDigits = digits(number / 10)
        let lastDigit = number % 10
        return firstDigits + [lastDigit]
    } else {
        return [number]
    }
}
```

I would rather approach the problems as follows. I wonder what is the advantages of having the above solution.

```
func digits(_ number:Int) -> [Int]
{
    if number >= 10 {
        let lastDigit = number % 10
        return digits(number / 10) + [lastDigit]
    } else {
        return [number]
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use the ternary operator and implicit return to make it even shorter (which is basically the only difference between the two functions.)

Comment: @JackBashford, I could able to come up with a single line. The question that I am asking related with the given solution at the top. I need a little bit of explanation of how  `let firstDigits` gets updated and store recursion result each time since it is immutable.

Comment: It's function-scoped - so it's a completely different constant each time `digits` is run. Doug Richardson addresses this in his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I wonder then how it could store the base result? And let variable is not mutable, how it updates?

`firstDigits` never changes, it is only set once *in each invocation of* `digits`. Each invocation of `digits` has it's own variables.

### Example Execution

In the following example I show how the execute proceeds as a series of substitutions.

```
digits(123) ->
digits(123 / 10)  + [123 % 10] ->
digits(12)  + [3] ->
digits(12 / 10) + [12 % 10]  + [3] ->
digits(1) + [2] + [3] ->
[1] + [2] + [3] ->
[1, 2, 3]
```

## Another way to write it that may be more clear

```swift
func digits(_ number:Int) -> [Int]
{
    if number >= 10 {
        return digits(number / 10) + [number % 10]
    } else {
        return [number]
    }
}
```